# How to count DOM elements in Cypress assertion

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I'm trying to count the number of options in a select element, and the number of elements of a certain class in the DOM.

I need to compare the two totals for a Cypress assertion.

I can select the options I need, and iterate over them with each(), and increment a counter that way. However, it's asynchronous, and it's also a clumsy solution. I'm certain that the object yielded by my cy.get() has a length property, I just can't seem to get at it.

Here is one of the things I expected to work. It logs *undefined* to the console.

```
cy.get('div[data-cy-type="group-component"]:first').as('firstGroup');
cy.get('@firstGroup').find('[name=group_id]').as('groupSelect');
console.log(cy.get('@groupSelect').children('option').length);
```

I know my alias is good and my cy.get() is yielding the correct select element.

If I do something like this:

```
cy.get('@groupSelect').children('option').each(function(){
    console.log(i++);
});
```

then it will iterate over each option. But it's asynchronous so not very helpful in this flow.

Comment: I don't understand your problem exactly, but this may help - `cy.get('@groupSelect').children('option').then(options => expect(options.length).to.eq(otherTotal))`. I'm not sure how the other total (count of class in DOM) is derived, perhaps if you post more code we can help further.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can leverage [Cypress.$](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/$.html#). Please note however that the documentation doesn't precisely advertise it as a testing tool:

> This is a great way to synchronously query for elements when debugging
>   from Developer Tools.

Anyhow, I believe something along this line will yield the value you expect:

```
selector = 'div[data-cy-type="group-component"]:first select[name=group_id] option'
count = Cypress.$(selector).length
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simple access the length property of a cypress selector.

```
cy.get('.elements')
        .its('length')
        .then(lengthOfClassElements => cy
           .get('select > option')
           .its('length')
           .then(lengthOfOptions => {
               expect(lengthOfClassElements).to.be.moreThan(lengthOfOptions)
           });
```

Comment: I'm trying to compare the quantity of options in the select against the quantity of elements selected by class. I'm not trying to assert that it has a fixed quantity, but that the two quantities match.

Comment: I haveb updated my answer, we first get the length of elements selected by class, then get the length of elements in the select element, then we do an assertion. Didnt test the code but it will work with slight tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that, for whatever reason, I need to chain `get` twice. The first `get` should select a parent element and then the second should select all the elements, which live under that parent, that you which to count.

```
const expectedCount = 5; // whatever count you expect
cy.get('.parentClass').get('.childClass').should('have.length', expectedCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the counting/length in one of my problem,
Similar suggestion here would be from-

```
cy.get('@groupSelect').children('option').length
```

to this-

```
cy.get('@groupSelect').children('option')
  .then((optionObj)=>{
    let count= Cypress.$(optionObj).length
    console.log('option count: ', count);
  })
```

Note: console.log can be used before cy.get() as well