# How to count dom elemnts with Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I would like to count the number of elements in the dom that are checked

Example :

```
cy.get('.p-multiselect-item .p-highlight').its('length');
```

Comment: Share the element html when its checked.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `p-multiselect-item` as a class (leading dot) but actually it's a tag.

Try

```js
cy.get('p-multiselect-item .p-highlight')  // find <p-multiselect-item> 
                                           // with children having class p-highlight
  .its('length')
  .should('eq', 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this :

```
cy.get('@groupSelect').children('option').length
```

if not you have some answer here :
[How to count DOM elements in Cypress assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609636/how-to-count-dom-elements-in-cypress-assertion)

Comment: thanks but 
I already tried but it doesn't work